# How can I create a ReadableStream from a File?

Tags: javascript

There's an NPM package I'd like to use called `pcap-parser`. It requires a  `ReadableStream` but I only have my pcap data as a `File`.

I've tried `const readableStream = new ReadableStream(file)`, and I've read through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/ReadableStream but can't find a simple example that converts a `File` into a `ReadableStream`.

Comment: I think there is an idea how to do in this code https://github.com/goto-bus-stop/from2-blob/blob/master/index.js

Comment: @ValeryBaranov Very helpful, thanks! I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/from2-blob and it works perfectly.